# Jest and file-loader import

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I'm currently importing a module using file loader in one of my files in a react app (CRA):

```
"file-loader?name=scripts/[name].[hash].js!jsstore/dist/jsstore.worker.min.js"
```

When running Jest, it throws this error:

```
Cannot find module 'file-loader?name=scripts/[name].[hash].js!jsstore/dist/jsstore.worker.min.js'
```

I've attempted different configs in package.json for Jest, by setting either modulePathIgnorePatterns and moduleNameMapper, but neither config setting works:

```
"modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "file-loader?name=scripts/[name].[hash].js!jsstore/dist/jsstore.worker.min.js"
      ]
```

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
        "file-loader?name=scripts/[name].[hash].js!jsstore/dist/jsstore.worker.min.js": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jsstore/dist/jsstore.worker.min.js"
      }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can map this import to a file that will return a `string` which what `file-loader` returns;

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  "^file\-loader":"<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
}
```

```js
// __mocks__/fileMock.js

module.exports = 'file-path-mock';
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `moduleNameMapper`, I totally missed that possibility!